# channel basicConsume consumer inner class is not GCed in jrabbitmq ava API

Tags: java, multithreading, rabbitmq, rpc, spring-rabbit

I am using rabbitmq rpc to fetch data in multi threaded env , I am following below

1. create single connection for entire application.
2. create one channel per thread.
3. create on consumer to consume from each thread and return back.

**Problem :**

1. My problem is 3rd I am not able to get rabbitmq java API which usages same consumer again and again.
2. In case I let each channel to create one consumer , that consumer is never GCed due to reason that is linked to a channel and that channel is never deleted (Point 2 from setup.) But if I delete channel each time It gets GCed.

Possible Approach to solve :

1. Should I create a concurrent HashMap and keep all consumers inside concurrent Hash Map and load it back and forth ?
2. rabbit mq basicGet() API : which seems to be very confusing :
    Somemtimes it returns null response while rpc-server continues to return correct value. Possible work around here is to put

   while(true){
   // keep polling.
   // break once you get data.
   }

This seems to be a hack to me.

I do not think any other option fits here.

Below is my code which i am using to consume data from rabbit mq rpc :

```
public String fetchDataFromRpc(String requestQueueName, byte[] message, Channel channel) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        final BlockingQueue<String> response = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();
        String replyQueueName = channel.queueDeclare().getQueue();
        String corrId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        System.out.println(" corr id : "+corrId);
        AMQP.BasicProperties props = new AMQP.BasicProperties.Builder().correlationId(corrId).replyTo(replyQueueName).build();
        channel.basicPublish("", requestQueueName, props, message);
        Consumer consumer = new DefaultConsumer(channel) {
            @Override
            public void handleDelivery(String consumerTag, Envelope envelope, AMQP.BasicProperties properties, byte[] body) throws IOException {
                if (properties.getCorrelationId().equals(corrId)) {
                    response.offer(new String(body, "UTF-8"));
                    channel.queueDelete(replyQueueName);
                    System.out.println(" res corr id : "+corrId);
                }
            }
        };
        channel.basicConsume(replyQueueName, true, consumer);

        return response.take();
    }
```

line :
channel.basicConsume(replyQueueName, true, consumer);
keeps creating new consumer every time threads comes to this block and old consumers never gets GCed , which I got it due to its linked to channel hence not being GCed so can I use HashMap to store all consumers per thread and keep loading from there ?.

Answer (score 0):

You should really `basicCancel()` the consumer when you are done.

However, you should get a `handleCancel()` call because you deleted the consumer's queue, so I don't see why the consumer wouldn't be GC'd.

It's not very efficient to create a temporary reply queue for each request. RabbitMQ now provides a special direct replyTo mechanism with a pseudo reply queue.

Why did you add the [spring-rabbitmq](/questions/tagged/spring-rabbitmq) tag? I see no spring code in your question.

On the other hand, if you are a Spring shop, the `RabbitTemplate.sendAndReceive()` (and `convertSendAndReceive()`) methods will take care of all of this for you (and [it uses direct replyTo, by default, if the broker is new enough](http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp//reference/html/_reference.html#direct-reply-to)).

Answer (score 0):

are you talking about something like below

```
@Override
public void handleDelivery(String consumerTag, Envelope envelope, AMQP.BasicProperties properties, byte[] body) throws IOException {
    if (properties.getCorrelationId().equals(corrId)) {
        response.offer(new String(body, "UTF-8"));
        channel.basicCancel(consumerTag);
        channel.queueDelete(replyQueueName);
    }
}
```